# Python wave readframes doesn't return all frames on windows

Tags: python, windows, wav, wave

I'm trying to get the byte string from a wavefile with the wave module:

```
import wave
wavfile = open(filename)
w = wave.open(wavfile)
print "nsamples:", w.getnframes()
print "sample size:", w.getsampwidth()
print "channels:", w.getnchannels()
data = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
print "number of samples read:", len(data) / (w.getsampwidth() * w.getnchannels())
```

On Unix systems, using the Anaconda installation, this works (for any given wavefile):

```
nsamples: 4800000
sample size: 3
channels: 1
number of samples read: 4800000
```

However on Windows systems, also using the Anaconda installation, this doesn't work (for any given wavefile):

```
nsamples: 4800000
sample size: 3
channels: 1
number of samples read: 443
```

The 443 samples read are equal to the first 443 samples of the 4800000. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, it wasn't an issue with the wave module:

```
wavfile = open(filename, 'rb')
```

as per: [Python Does Not Read Entire Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905874/python-does-not-read-entire-text-file)