# Python will Sometimes Not Read in Entire File

Tags: python, io, enumeration

I have python 2.7 program used on a unix server that reads in an ASCII file with two types of information and processes that information. I have put this process into a function that essentially does:

```
def read_info()
    f = open(file_name, 'rb')
    f_enumerator = enumerate(f, start=1)
    for i, line in f_enumerator:
        process_info
    process_last_info
```

When this function is called on the file from my main program, it stops at a seemingly arbitrary point halfway through a line towards the end of the input file, whereas when the function is called from a simple wrapper on the same input file it reads the entire file correctly.

I have tried one of the solutions here:  [Python Does Not Read Entire Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905874/python-does-not-read-entire-text-file)  , Where the file is read in as binary but that did not fix the problem.
The other solution there (reading in the file in chunks) would be problematic as I am trying to parse the file on a line-specific basis, and reading in a chunks of text would require a lot more parsing.

I would be willing to do that, except that the intermittent nature of the problem suggests to me that there might be some other solution?

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things.  Is this a text file, and if so do you get the same issue without the `'b'` (you imply you do, just checking).  Is the file a Windows file, and which OS are you running on?  The iteration does a read-ahead, which could explain the apparent random-ness.

Comment: Also, which version of Python do you use?

Comment: @Dan: since you found the problem cause, maybe you can post your solution, along with your considerations for the `with`  usage as an answer - it could therefore be accepted as the right answer for the question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I realized it was a simple mistake on my part and I've edited accordingly.

In answer to the questions: It is a text file. In a similar problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905874/python-does-not-read-entire-text-file ) it was suggested that reading in as binary may fix the problem which is why I changed the mode to 'rb'. 
Details: Python 2.7, Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On further reflection I realized it was because I had created the file earlier in the program and had not closed the file handle, and this was therefore perhaps a buffering issue. Closing the file earlier fixed the problem.

It was suggested that I use "with" syntax for writing to the file originally:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    do foo
```

This would indeed have prevented me from forgetting to close the file, and prevented this problem.

Comment: actually, re-opening the file for read using with won't change your original porblem. Oppening it for writting using with would do, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_info():
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
       for i, a_line in enumerate(f,1): #a_line must end with a newline
            process_info(a_line,i)
    # you have processed whole file here so no need for `process_last_info`
```

using `with` will ensure your filehandle is closed (you should especially do this when writing to a file but really its always good practice)...

on further information from OP I believe a generator would be an ideal solution to his problem

```
def data_gen(f):
   header = None
   lines = []
   for line in f:
       if line.startswith(">"): #header
          if header is not None: #if its not the first line basically
             yield header,lines 
          header = line #set the header
          lines = [] #reinitialize lines
       else:
          lines.append(line)
    yield header,lines # the last section

def read_info(fname):
    with open(fname,"rb") as f:
        for header,lines in data_gen(f):
            process(header,lines)
```

Comment: Why is with open() as f: superior to f = open() and f.close()? In the full version of my code process_last_info is indeed necessary, based on the way the two types of information are stored sequentially.

Comment: `with` guarantees the filehandle will be closed ... even if you encounter errors ... why wouldnt you have a line outside of read_info do your sequentially things ... this sounds like an XY problem... what are you actually trying to do... do you want to go through the file 2 lines at a time?

Comment: -1 for a "I have no idea" syntactically incorrect answer, keeping the only explicit problem in the OP code unchanged and uncomented - namely opening a text file in the `'rb'` mode.

Comment: I see, in answering my own question perhaps I've demonstrated the exact utility of the "with" syntax. The file read in a title line followed by a variable number of data lines, with the data being processed when the next title line is reached or the file ends.

Comment: @jsbueno its syntactically correct ... and there is no error with opening a textfile as `rb` ... he never said it only contained ascii characters

Comment: @Dan I believe a generator would be ideal for this problem ... how do you know how many lines to read from the header(title?) and what does the title actually look like

Comment: It did indeed contain only ascii characters, but the other question/solution suggested reading in as binary may have addressed an early, mistaken reading of EOF.

Comment: The syntax error is still there :-)  . And opening a file in "rb" for reading as text is _semantically_ incorrect. Although it is not Python's behavior, interating over a file open in binary mode should yield each byte as an element of the file (not each text line)

Comment: (btw, Since I didn't produe an answer, rather just posted the fix in a visible way for other people hitting here, I marked my post as "community wiki" - maye you should take another action in a wiki answer than downvoting it for petty revenge). While you are at it, just add the ":" missing to fix your syntax so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: ok I fixed it .... you were right i overlooked that ... if you edit your answer I guess I will remove the downvote ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thank you for posting the generator. However doesn't it require a fixed number of lines of data? The number of data lines (aka continuous data string broken by newlines) is variable.

Comment: you would get the N_LINES from the header I assumed? thats why I asked what your headers looked like :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley Unfortunately no. Oh sorry I did not see that question. The header can, but is not required to, contain the length of the subsequent data string. Most often it's ">[Name]" and sometimes ">[Name and Data]".

Comment: ok so it starts with ">" ? and regular lines dont? is there a blank line or something right before?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I was reading a new data header as occuring when ">" is found at the beginning of the line, as it is not allowed in that position in the data. Yes that's correct. No blank lines.

Comment: @JoranBeasley While this wasn't the answer to the question, this is a very nice solution to my original problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the O.P. found out, the problem was the file had been created previously on the same program, but had not been flushed or closed properly before the reading attempt.