# ifstream::read fails at ASCII 26

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ascii, visual-c++-2010

This problem has been bugging me for a long time. For example, the code

```
ifstream in;
char temp;
int a;

in.open ("Random.txt");

for (a = 0;a < 10000;a++)
    in.read (&temp, 1);

in.close ();
```

works fine until the `ifstream` encounters a substitute character (ASCII = 26). Then, for all following characters, `ifstream::read` gives me `temp = -1`. I don't really want this to happen, but instead want it to keep on reading characters from the file instead of `-1`. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Not an answer, but a commment... Isn't 26 the ASCII character for end of file (EOF) ? I would look at the runtime.

Comment: yes... I totally forgot about that. But my program reads in data which contain all sorts of data, and so it's not REALLY the end of file when I read in 26.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to open the stream in binary mode. For historic reasons the text mode on Windows will consider Control-Z (ASCII 26) as the end of a file.

There are more details [in this earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/405169/5987).

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem! Thank you. I can't accept your answer now, but will do so in 7 minutes when SO allows me to.