# How to read text file with 1Ah char in it?

Tags: python, text, ascii

I have a file, which is an assembly source with comments. These comments contain 1Ah character. It is a control character, the "substitute", but it also prints a nice right arrow in DOS, so someone long time ago thought it would be a shame not to use it.

Somehow, it works like end of file character for Python. All I do is:

```
f = open('file.asm')
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()
```

And everything goes ok just until the first entrance of 1Ah.

The question is, how to read this symbol along with other text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405058/line-reading-chokes-on-0x1a

Comment: Why do you say everything goes ok until the first entrance? What happens next? Break lines in places it shouldn't?

Comment: @PauloBu, 1Ah is a good old `EOF` character - this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: It works exactly like correct EOF. File just "ends".

Comment: This problem is on Windows only. User 'rb' file mode to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file using universal line ending support:

```
f = open('file.asm', 'rU')
```

This avoids opening the file in native-platform text mode (in the C call) and prevents Windows from interpreting the `\x1a` code point as a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
f = open('file.asm', 'rb')
```

It should open file in binary mode.